How to generate a lambda expression from this T-SQL code
I have SQL code like this:
select * 
from [groups]
where Id in (select GroupId from groupUsers where UserId = @UserId)

I want to generate a lambda code that returns the result exactly like the above code:
_context.Groups.where(g => g.Id == ...???)


_context.Groups.where(g => groupUsers.Any(q => q.GroupId == g.Id && q=>q.UserId == @UserId))

Only tag the technologies you want the answer in.

Or perhaps _context.groupUsers.Where(gu => gu.UserId == userId).Select(gu => gu.group), if the groupUsers to group relationship is defined in your model. This will likely translate to a JOIN query. If you really want a WHERE ... IN (...) query (and not JOIN or EXISTS(...)), you may need something like the more verbose _context.Groups.Where(g => _context.groupUsers.Where(gu => gu.UserId == userId).Select(gu => gu.GroupId).Contains(g.Id)).

I found the correct code. it is:
_context.Groups.where(g => _context.GroupUsers.Any(u => u.GroupId == g.Id && u.UserId == @UserId))

Regard to Rachel!
